# Memory allotment in C++

Tags: c++, memory

Whenever I'm introducing variables and printing their addresses, then apparently they tend to be stored in places with regular spacing, starting from the first or the last variable I introduced (depends on the compiler).

Does C++ actually allot memory in a way that all the variables introduced at a particular time are given their memory n a line? If so, then isn't it bad for memory management, because then the compiler will have to ensure that it finds enough space to give memory to all the variables we have introduced in a line?

Eg.

```
int a, b, c;
```

When I print `&a`, `&b`, `&c`,
then the answer on one of the compilers that I have is:

```
0xbffe2534
0xbffe2538
0xbffe253c
```

And as you can see `&b-&a=4` and `&c-&b=4`

On another compiler, the answer is:

```
0xbffe2534
0xbffe2538
0xbffe253c
```

And again `&b-&a=4` and `&c-&b=4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't prescribe any particular memory allocation strategy.

What you're seeing is the most common strategy for non-static local variables and arguments. They're typically allocated on the **machine stack**. The standard requires that they are destroyed in opposite order of creation, and so the machine stack allocation strategy is simply to add the next required variable at the end of the currently used area (typically downward in memory), and when execution exit the block, free memory by simply shrinking the in-use area.

Note that this strategy works well with ordinary function calls, where you have nested pairs of calls and returns, but not so well with with coroutines, where you have more arbitrary transfers of control. For this to work with coroutines each has to be outfitted with a sufficiently large contiguous area of memory to use as stack, and that can be costly for fine-grained abstractions. A linked list representation of a stack can then work better, but I don't know of any C++ compiler that supports that (probably because the standard library doesn't support coroutines).

When you use multiple threads each will in practice have its own contiguous area stack. This is not as bad as it might sound because threads are often use for more heavy-weight processing than coroutines, with just a few threads.

Disclaimer: I haven't taken the time to educate myself about the myriad multi-processing technologies pouring forth the last 2-3 years. So it might well be that even Visual C++, which I'm familiar with for conventional programming, might support linked stacks, as a language extension for some context.

Answer (score 0):

Memory allotment in C++ is completely implementation dependent.  C++ compilers can do whatever they want and will change from platform to platform and from version to version.  There is a general standard that most C++ compilers comply to but that has nothing to do with C++ *per say*.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are allocating memory, variables will be placed on the stack. What this means is that when you declare, it get's pushed on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29). Look at this code:

```
void f(int a){
  int b=a;
  if(a) 
    f(a-1);
  printf("%i, %i\n", a, b");
}
```

Here when the processor enters function f, it pushes b onto the stack to have a place to store it. Then it calls f again. Now we cannot store b in the same location as the previous call, because we still need that value. So every time you enter a function (or actually a scope) your local varables are pushed on the stack, and remain there until you leave that function (scope) again.

There is one other way of allocating memory, and that is called the heap. That is done by `malloc()` in c or `new int` int c++. I'm not going to explain this now. Just google it ;) and remember to `free()` or `delete`